# Sql loop over unique elements of a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get data of rows into columns. This is my data before query.

[image]

This is my query.

```
SELECT
    Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Art") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Art,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Action") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Action,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Board") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Board,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Puzzle") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Puzzle,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Adventure") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Adventure,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Others") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Others
FROM 
    __table__
GROUP BY 
    Date
```

After Query this is my data.

[image]

Which is fine and intended data. But problem is in query as you can see I have to explicitly write each term. I want to automate that using loop. Theoretical solution is to write subquery to get all unique terms and then loop over them. But I don't know how.

Comment: Do you want `sql` solution or `pandas`? If `sql`, please tag the RDBMS that you are using along with its version. E.g `Oracle11g`, `SQL Server 2019` etc.,

Comment: using sqlite for Python

Comment: SQLite does not support pivoting data, so you will have to write each term.